# Parsing delimited input with optional entires

Tags: java, parsing, csv

What is the best way to parse a file with optional entries?

i.e.  I have input of the form

```
item1,item2,[item3],[item4],item5,item6
```

where item3 and item4 are both optional entries.  I'm currently splitting along the delimiters and filling the objects based on the number of entries given.  Is there a better way to make this happen?

Comment: Do you have a way to distinguish between item3 and item4 if only one of them is given?

Comment: Sort of.  item3 is a middle name and item4 is a suffix (Jr,Sr,etc), so I could try and detect the difference but the records I'm parsing are not consistent in how they format the suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:
1. Rearrange the data so that the optional items are at the end of the file.
2. Pass delimiters for the missing data. This is preferable, as it would allow you to maintain the shape of the data.